# How to prevent Android Material DatePickerDialog from selecting future dates

Tags: android

I am trying to create a `DatePickerDialog` which will not allow the user to select something in the future. I see many solutions that say that I should use 
`setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());` but this does not work with the material dialog thing. It does prevent to user to select beyond the current month, however future dates in this month are just grayed out but still selectable. See my code below.

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(rootView.getContext(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(final DatePicker datePicker, final int year, final int monthOfYear, final int dayOfMonth) {
        dateTime = dateTime.withYear(year);
        dateTime = dateTime.withMonthOfYear(monthOfYear + 1);
        dateTime = dateTime.withDayOfMonth(dayOfMonth);

        if (dateTime.isAfter(DateTime.now())) {
            dateTime = new DateTime();
            Snackbar.make(rootView, R.string.future_date_not_allowed, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        setDateTime(dateTime);
    }
}, dateTime.getYear(), dateTime.getMonthOfYear() - 1, dateTime.getDayOfMonth());

dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
dialog.show();
```

As you might see, we are using Jodatime to offload some complexity. I now check once the user has selected the date, if is really not in the future, even though I already specified it using `setMaxDate`.

In the image below you can see that today is July 23, and I've selected July 29. If I press ok, my SnackBar would show. Everything later than today is grayed, but still selectable.... Don't even get me started on the TimePicker ;)

[image: Picker example]

**TL;DR**

How can I **actually** prevent the user from selecting future dates?

Comment: May I suggest you to avoid the system date and time picker? They have issues with Samsung Lollipop devices, and the lack of functionality requires you to write extra code. My favourite lib: [times-square](https://github.com/square/android-times-square)

Comment: Any solution for this problem till now ??

Answer (score -1):

You can use this to prevent future date.

```
mDatePicker.setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```